# Pulling content from Div Tag Declaration with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull out some content inside of a div tag declaration:

```
<div class="search-listing font-size-10 my-3 my-md-0 py-0 py-md-4" listing_id="5327969" latitude="28.92327" longitude="-27.0365">
.
.
.
</div>
```

What I want is the latitude & longitude. But I can't seem to be able to access the content inside of the div declaration itself. I can only get into the children items. I'm using html.parser

if I try to do:

```
line.select('div[class*py-md-4"]')[0])
```

I get an index error.

This was never going to work:

```
coords = soup.find_all("longitude")
```

I've tried:

```
divisions = soup.select('div[class*=search-listing]')

for line in divisions:

     print(line.select('div[class*=py-md-4]')[0])
```

but each time I try to extract items from line - it gives me the children of the div.

I am expecting to be able to pull out both the longitude & latitude from the Div - but to no avail. Surely it must be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `[latitude][longitude]`. This will select every tag that has defined attributes `latitude=` **and** `longitude=`:

```
data = '''<div class="search-listing font-size-10 my-3 my-md-0 py-0 py-md-4" listing_id="5327969" latitude="28.92327" longitude="-27.0365">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('[latitude][longitude]'):
    print('lat={} lon={}'.format(tag['latitude'], tag['longitude']))
```

Prints:

```
lat=28.92327 lon=-27.0365
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!